# Clear input box when input:invalid in html using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, textbox

My goal is to clear an input type text box when they are focused ONLY IF the input is INVALID.
Let's say i have a text box that has a maximum value of 200

```
<input id="textbox" type = "text" max="200" runat="server">
```

so let's say I input 150 so it's valid hence if I focus again on it, it will remain its value 150
but, if i input greater than 200, my text box will have have a red border color on it and focused on another textbox(its working on my current code) and if i will focus on it again, i want to clear its value.

I wanna do something like this.

```
 input:invalid {
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 3px #e74c3c;
    }

    input:focus:invalid {
        textbox.value = "" (i know this will not work,
                            but i wanna do something like this but how?)
    }
```

Note that I have multiple textboxes with different max and min values, not just one.

Comment: Just tried given pure java script code it doesn't need of JQuery library

Comment: did you also want the second `textbox` to be cleared if the first 1 is?

Comment: Looks like your mixing Css and js in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ValidityState](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ValidityState) interface which enables you to check the state of each input field. First you need to listen `onfocus` event. For example:

```
var form = document.querySelector('form'),
    elements = form.querySelectorAll('input'), 
    i;

for (i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].addEventListener('focus', function() {
        if (!this.validity.valid) {
            this.value = '';
        }
    }, false);
}
```

#### Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yrovm6uh/

Comment: thanks, this solved my problem. The other answers also work but this contains less code.

Answer (score 1):

Please Try this pure JavaScript:

```js
function myFunction(control,max,min){

    var val= Number(control.value);

       if(val>max || val<min){
        control.value="";
      }
    
    }
```

```html
<input id="textbox" type = "text" max="200" onFocus="myFunction(this,250,100)">
```

Let assume your max value is 250 and min value is 100

Comment: is there a better way to substitute the value of 200 into only max value? because i have many textboxes, not only the 200.

Comment: I didnt get what you want. Could you explain it clearly?

Comment: thanks @Amol its working, but the answer above has minimal code, ill use that one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what your after, it changes red once it reaches the `max` amount of characters which is taken from the value in the `input`

At that point it also focuses on a seperate `textbox` with the cursor in it ready for the user to continue typing which uses its own `max` character value before turning red it self.

And if a user then clicks on the first `textbox` that turned red it will be cleared and the code below has the ability to clear the second `textbox` at the same time.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":input").on("focus keyup", function(){
        var max = $(this).attr("max");
        var current = $(this).val().length;

        if(current < max){
            $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid blue", "outline" : "none"});
        }else{
            $(this).css({"border" : "1px solid red", "outline" : "none"});
            $(this).focus(function(){
                $(this).val(" ").focus();
                //add this if you want the overflow textbox to be cleared aswell
                //$("#overflow").val(" ").css({"border" : "", "outline" : "none"});
            });
            $("#overflow").focus(); 
        }
    });
});
```

you can see it in action [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/dLyr479s/)

Hope this helps

Comment: i already have a code like this, my only problem is only about clearing of value when invalid and focused. I already accepted an answer, ill just upvote this. Ill use this as a future reference. thanks

Answer (score 0):

using java script:

```
<input id="textbox" type = "text" max="200" onFocus="validate(this)">
```

JS:

```
function validate(control){
    var val= parseInt(control.value);

    if(val>200){
        control.value="";
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solution doesn't scale. Imaging that there is another field with `required` validation rule. You can't use `validate` function for it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use jquery and bind focus like

```
$('#textbox').bind('focus', function() {

    if ( $('#textbox').val().length>200 ) { 

        $('#textbox').val('');

    }

});
```

can bind keyup event as well, it'll clear the textbox the moment user types more than 200 like.

```
$('#textbox').bind('keyup', function(e) {

    if ( $('#textbox').val().length>200 ) { 

        $('#textbox').val('');

    }

});
```

fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/invincibleJai/Laqeh79u/

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest:

```
$('input').on('invalid', function () {
    this.value = '';
});
```

References:

- [`invalid` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/invalid).

Comment: i'd like to use this because i have multiple textboxes, but it seem s to be not working, can you link me a working fiddle for this?

Comment: Unfortunately I'm on iPad, which makes that really difficult, so no; I'd imagine your need to use the `pattern` attribute, and `type="number"` though. Incidentally, I did just fix a typo 'imvalid'/'invalid' which may be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<input id="textbox" type = "text" max="200" runat="server">
```

in Jquery :

```
$("#textbox-id").focus(function(){
if($(this).val() > 200)
{
  $(this).val("");
  $(this).css("border","1px solid red");
}
```

});